# Testing daylight savings change

Tags: linux, date, dst

I have a small problem with the date command in Linux if anyone can help, I use it to jump forward in time to trigger our billing process so we can test things quickly.

The problem I have is when I run

```
date --set="OCT 27 01:00:59 BST 2012 2 day"
```

The return date I get is Mon Oct 29 00:00:59 GMT 2012 which is correct as it takes the day light savings in to account.

But when I run

```
date --set="MAR 30 00:00:59 GMT 2013 3 day"
```

I get Apr 2 00:00:59 BST 2013 which is wrong because what I want is Apr 2 01:00:59 BST 2013.

Why does it work one way around and not the other and what would be the best way to deal with the scenario?

Thanks

Comment: According [to this](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/europe/uk/time/british-summer-time/) your second command doesn't actually straddle the dalight savings time change for BST (it occurs on March 25), so I'm not sure why you'd expect an extra hour shift

Comment: It is daylight saving in the singular.  This is not the Daylight Savings and Loan, you know.

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo The clock does shift again on the 31st of march 2013 according to the same site you gave. So still a problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to: http://ascending.wordpress.com/2008/04/03/how-linux-handles-summer-time/
use

```
zdump -v Europe/Chisinau
```

for your region to see when your system will add/remove an extra DST-hour

But actually you requested a date in BST (British Summer Time) 1 day after the DST switch, in the other case you requested a date in GMT 2 days into the DST switch, but GMT does not have a Daylight savings time offset.